# a list of pygame sprites loses its first element, and gains a duplicate of the last

Tags: python, list, pygame

I have a function that loads a sprite sheet, finds a block of sprites, and then puts each individual sprite into a list.  Before it appends a sprite into the list, it will blit it onto the screen.  Once it's done loading sprites, it will then iterate through the list, blitting each sprite as it goes.  The two sets of blits *should* be identical, but instead the first sprite is dropped from the list, and the last sprite is duplicated.  The two sets of blits look like this:

[image]

Each sprite is blitted in the order it was appended to the list, going from left to right, top to bottom, so the first sprite is the top left one, and the last is the bottom right.

Here's the function that loads the sprites:

```
def assembleSprites(name, screen):
    """Given a character name, this function will return a list of all that
    character's sprites.  This is used to populate the global variable spriteSets"""
    spriteSize = (35, 35)
    spritesheet = pygame.image.load("./images/patchconsprites.png")
    sprites = []
    start = charCoords[name]
    char = list(start)
    image = pygame.Surface((35,35))

    # load each sprite and blit them as they're added to the list
    for y in range(5):
        char[0] = start[0]
        for x in range(9):
            rect = (char[0], char[1], char[0]+spriteSize[0], char[1]+spriteSize[1])
            image.blit(spritesheet, (0,0), rect)
            image = image.convert()
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
            screen.blit(image, (x*40, y*40))
            pygame.display.update()
            sprites.append(image)
            char[0] += spriteSize[0]+2
        char[1] += spriteSize[1]+2

    # check that the list was constructed correctly
    count = 0
    for y in range(6,11):
        for x in range(9):
            screen.blit(sprites[count], (x*40,y*40))
            count += 1
    pygame.display.update()
    return sprites
```

Anyone see how I'm screwing the list up?

Comment: try update display after each blit for the second set. See what is actually inside `sprites`.

Comment: @SilentGhost: They display the same way as they do in the picture, just one at a time.

Comment: Standalone code (+link to the source png file) might come handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
image.blit(spritesheet, (0,0), rect)
```

You haven't re-initialised `image` each time around the loop, it's still the same surface you used in the previous iteration, a surface that is already in the list. Each time round the loop you overwrite the sprite you appended to the list in the previous step.

I suggest grabbing a new `image= pygame.Surface((35,35))` immediately before the line instead of before the start of the loop.